# Adding multiple lists all into one list Python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

Given  a list of lists, return a single list, containing all of
the elements in the list of lists. The elements of the lists can be of any type.

**Sample Run**

```
given_list = [[42,'bottles'], ['of','water','on','the'], ['wall']]
new_list = [42, 'bottles', 'of', 'water', 'on' , 'the', 'wall']
```

I sort of got my code to work but unlike this sample run I would like the user to enter 2 things for 3 lists and then add those three lists all into one.
While keeping those spate lists in the given_list how do I put them all into one big list for new_list?

Comment: you can just concatenate lists with `new_List = list1+list2+list3`

Comment: WOW thanks! But now another question... If I were to use the code in the sample run: given_list= [ [42,'bottles'] , ['of','water','on','the'] , ['wall']] How would I put all 3 of these lists into one big new_List?

Comment: When i search quickly for 1) combine lists, 2) merge lists i get plenty of answers, why not searching first before asking?

Answer (score 3):

You can use extend:

```
list1 = [42,'bottles']
list2 = ['of','water','on','the']
list3 = ['wall']
new_List = []

new_List.extend(list1)
new_List.extend(list2)
new_List.extend(list3)


print new_List
```

output:
[42, 'bottles', 'of', 'water', 'on', 'the', 'wall']

Comment: Thanks but if I were to use the sample run with given_list= [ [42,'bottles'] , ['of','water','on','the'] , ['wall']] then how would I turn that all into one new list?

Comment: @poop given_list being a list of lists, you would just have to loop through that and extend new_list with each inner list.

Comment: Yes, use Andy's answer for nested lists.

Answer (score 2):

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(given_list))?

You could even use sum(given_list, []). Probably not very efficient since it creates lots of intermediary lists.

edit: I should clarify the itertools method is efficient. If you don't want to use a library you could also try [i for inner_list in given_list for i in inner_list].

Comment: is there a way to do that without using this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through all of the lists:

```
for item in list1:
    new_List.append(item)
```

etc.